# How to make AuthorizeAttribute derived type instantiate every time request comes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a AuthorizeAttribute derived type, that keeps in memory once it has been instantiated. Is is possible to make it instantiate every time when request comes in.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Definitely an XY Problem, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Look for Stateful filters, maybe help you with your problem.
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/aspnet-mvc-filters-and-statefulness.html

Answer (score 0):

The Global.asax file has a method called RegisterGlobalFilters.
You can use this to add filters (like error handling or custom authentication) to every request across all controllers.

```
  public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomAttributeForEveryRequest());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

All you need to do is call this method from your OnApplicationStarted event in Global.asax..

```
 protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    }
```

Does that help?

Comment: The AuthorizeAttribute derived type does NOT require the registration like what you mention.